# Motor efficiency experiment

Tags: electric-circuits, experimental-physics

I want to try and measure the efficiency of the motor by varying voltage. So my independent variable will be voltage and dependent variable will be power. However when i actually am doing the experiment when i change voltage current also changes which means i get more than one dependent variable. So my question is, if i change voltage and current changes is this normal and still keep my experiment as “ how voltage affects efficiency ?”. Also why does changing voltage also change current ?

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that changing voltage will also change current. Your experiment will need to account for that.

Efficiency is defined as the output mechanical power divided by the input electrical power. The input electrical power is the voltage times the current. Because increasing the voltage increases the current you will typically find that the power increases at a faster rate than the voltage increases.

So you will need to measure the current anyway in order to calculate the power and the efficiency. You will indeed have multiple dependent variables, but that is fine.

Changing the voltage changes the current because the motor has some internal impedance. This impedance means essentially that the current is proportional to the voltage. So increasing the voltage drives a larger current and therefore a larger power.